# How can I ensure that PyPi searches return accurate versions?

Tags: python, setuptools, software-distribution, pypi

When I search (in the search box at the top of the webpage) in PyPi for a package I've updated a few times over the past months, the results returned are often missing the most recent update, and include (some, but not all) versions that are no longer available.

Why do the search results on PyPi fail to correspond to the versions actually available? Is here a way for me, as the package maintainer, to force an index update (or something) to ensure that the results returned by search correspond to the versions available?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this question. The package I maintain (pi3d) has 'suddenly' started showing multiple versions when searched for. All apart from the latest are hidden and I haven't had this problem over the last two and a half years and 20 version releases!